# Insert nth row based on input entry

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, mysqli

The following code runs well:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add_bscint'])) {
    $req_field = array('bsc_id','int_no');
    validate_fields($req_field);
    $bsc_id = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['bsc_id']));
    $intno = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['int_no']));

    if(empty($errors)) {
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO bsc_int (bsc_id,bscint_no)";
        $sql .= " VALUES ('{$bsc_id}','{$intno}')";
    } else {
        $session->msg("d", $errors);
        redirect('bsc_int.php',false);
    }
}
?>
```

Instead of adding a single row, I would like to add a row based on the value entry in `$_POST['int_no']`.

So if the input entry is `5`, it will insert 5 rows, numbered `int.1`..`int.5`, as shown below:

```
bsc_id    intno
name1     int.1
name1     int.2
name1     int.3
name1     int.4
name1     int.5
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Added question, formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop with a for loop until you reach the entered integer.

Something like this:-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add_bscint']))
{
    $req_field = array('bsc_id','int_no');
    validate_fields($req_field);
    $bsc_id = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['bsc_id']));
    $intno = (int)$_POST['int_no'];

    for($icnt = 1; $icnt <= $intno; $icnt++)
    {
        $insert_array[] = "('$bsc_id','$icnt')";
    }


    if(empty($errors))
    {
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO bsc_int (bsc_id,bscint_no)";
        $sql .= " VALUES ".implode(",", $insert_array)."";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $session->msg("d", $errors);
        redirect('bsc_int.php',false);
    }
}
?>
```

But you probably need to check that the entered number is sensible (and if coping with large numbers, probably need to do multiple inserts rather than rolling them all up into one)

Comment: Thanks Kickstart... this works fine. It's a kind of relief rather than encoding it manually :)